# Custom expression for RavenDB where clause: field contains any item from provided array

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, ravendb

Could you please help reviewing the expressions which neither seem to work?

Trying to find records where a record property `@In` a provided array of values.

RavenDB 3.5 throwing exception that it did not manage to understand specified expression.

I am trying to avoid using the client sdk and resolve this with custom expressions, either with a similar sdk `.In` extension or `Enumerable.Any`.

Any help is appreciated

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'Could not understand expression
```

```csh
void Main()
{
    var exp = ByPersonNameIn(new[] { "Walter" });
    //var exp = ByPersonNameAny(new[] { "Walter" });

    var persons = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person { Name = "Walter" },
        new Person { Name = "Jesse" },
        new Person { Name = "Walter" },
    };

    // Expression works here, but not at IRavenQueryable.Where
    var res = persons.Where(exp.Compile()).ToList();
    res.Dump(nameof(res));
}

private Expression<Func<Person, bool>> ByPersonNameIn(string[] names)
{
    var person = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "person");
    var personProp = Expression.PropertyOrField(person, nameof(Person.Name));
    var namesParam = Expression.Constant(names, typeof(string[]));

    var @in = typeof(StringExt).GetMethod("In", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(IEnumerable<string>) });
    var inExp = Expression.Call(@in, personProp, namesParam);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(inExp, person);
}

private Expression<Func<Person, bool>> ByPersonNameAny(string[] names)
{
    var person = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "person");
    var name = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "name");
    var namesParam = Expression.Constant(names, typeof(string[]));

    var @eq = Expression.Equal(name, (Expression.PropertyOrField(person, nameof(Person.Name))));

    var @any = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Any", new[] { typeof(string) }, namesParam, Expression.Lambda(@eq, name));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(@any, person);
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public static class StringExt
{
    public static bool In(this string field, IEnumerable<string> values)
    {
        return values.Any(value => field.Equals(value));
    }

    public static bool In(this string field, params string[] values)
    {
        return values.Any(value => field.Equals(value));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some "luck" mimicking `@In` as `OR`, which is not ideal, but should work for the time being until I find something better.

```csh
        private static Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>> ByPropertyViaEqOr<TDocument>(string propName, string[] values)
        {
            var doc = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TDocument), "doc");
            var eq = values.Select(value => ByPropertyViaEq<TDocument>(propName, value));
            var orElse = eq.Aggregate((l, r) => Expression.OrElse(l, r));

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<TDocument, bool>>(orElse, doc);
        }

        private static Expression ByPropertyViaEq<TDocument>(string propName, string value)
        {
            var doc = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TDocument), "doc");
            var docProp = Expression.PropertyOrField(doc, propName);
            var propValue = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string));

            return Expression.Equal(docProp, propValue);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The RavenDB library has code in its LINQ provider to translate queries on a `IRavenQueryable` to queries RavenDB can understand (RQL). This translation is limited to the methods (and operators, etc) it is specifically written to handle, and when you bring it something it doesn't understand, like your own extension method, then it throws the exception to indicate that you have "fallen off the edge".

Most LINQ providers understand the pattern `var personNames = new[]{ "Walter" }; something .Where(person => personNames.Contains(person))` to do what you want - ie where [Enumerable.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netframework-4.8) is used to do an `IN`/any query. I think constructing the expression tree to use this method will work. Just plain using it in the LINQ query directly instead of the custom method would also work in your example. There doesn't seem to be a way to extend the LINQ provider to teach it how your method would be translated.

Comment: Thanks. Lambda exp `person => personNames.Contains(person)` is not understood neither. I am trying to avoid relying on ravendb in the domain of query building, but looks like will have to change it.

Comment: It sounds like the DocumentQuery API has a [WhereIn](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.1/csharp/client-api/session/querying/document-query/what-is-document-query) method which you could use. Apparently the LINQ queries compile down to DocumentQuery queries. But it sounds like if you want to just rely on IEnumerable/LINQ-looking things and hide the RavenDB-ness of RavenDB, you're out of luck. Even so, missing Enumerable.Contains looks pretty bad for a LINQ provider - the very first LINQ to SQL version supported it.

Comment: thanks mate, out of luck with `WhereIn`, using raven 3.5.x. I did a `OrElse` modification to it, see my answer pls. Not ideal, will look into improving it.